# julia JSON.parse losing type information

Tags: json, types, julia

I just started to learn julia but I have this issue:

I am trying to use julia's `JSON.parse` to parse a matrix (a list of coordinates) but it is losing the type information.

```
coords = JSON.parse("[[1.0,-2.0],[3.0,4.0],[5.0,-1.2]]")
```

it is returning the `Any` type instead of the `Float` type:

```
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 {1.0,-2.0}
 {3.0,4.0} 
 {5.0,-1.2}
```

How do i get (or convert this) to an Array of floats?

**Edit.**
Here is the larger problem:

```
taxi_df = readtable("./test.csv")
coords = [JSON.parse(x) for x in taxi_df[:POLYLINE]]
times = [float(length(x)*15) for x in coords]
df_submission = DataFrame()
df_submission[:TRIP_ID] = taxi_df[:TRIP_ID]
mean_time = mean(times)
df_submission[:TRAVEL_TIME] = [max(x, mean_time) for x in times]
writetable("submission.csv", df_submission)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its doing that in the first place because that data is a list-of-lists in JSON, so it can't convert to a matrix.

You can do

```
float(hcat(coords...))
```

if those are columns, or

```
float(hcat(coords...))'
```

if they are rows. If efficiency is critical for this code, can also just preallocate the output matrix and use a for loop, e.g.

```
A = zeros(3,2)
for i in 1:3, j in 1:2
  @inbounds A[i,j] = coords[i][j]
end
```