# Ways of taking care of JSON with Matrix data on Julia

Tags: arrays, json, matrix, julia

I am in a Julia project and I am trying to write code for saving Matrix data as .json file.
The problem I am facing is when I read the json string from the file and parse it, the Matrix is changed into "vector of vectors".

```
In [1]:
n=10
mat = zeros(n,n)
data = Dict(
    "n" => n,
    "mat" => mat
)
using JSON
output_text = JSON.json(data)
out = open("jsonTest.json","w")
println(out,output_text)
close(out)


In [2]:
data


Out[2]:
Dict{String, Any} with 2 entries:
  "mat" => [0.0 0.0 … 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 … 0.0 0.0; … ; 0.0 0.0 … 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.…
  "n"   => 10


In [3]:
op = JSON.parsefile("jsonTest.json")


Out[3]:
Dict{String, Any} with 2 entries:
  "mat" => Any[Any[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], Any[0.0, …
  "n"   => 10
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554092/julia-json-parse-losing-type-information), one simple solution is using `hcat` function to re-convert "vector of vectors" to "matrix" when reading the json.

It works, but it is a bit messy(and might time-consuming) to take care of each matrix in the json. Is there simpler way?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since JSON (the spec) does not know about Matrix, you need to either do nested vectors (as you're right now), or `reshape`.

I personally prefer `reshape` because its memory layout is the same as an concrete `Matrix` in Julia and `reshap` has no allocation and less overhead over `hcat`

```
julia> a = rand(2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.534246  0.282277  0.140581
 0.841056  0.443697  0.427142

julia> as = JSON3.write(a)
"[0.5342463881378705,0.8410557102859995,0.2822771326129221,0.44369703601566,0.1405805564055571,0.4271417199755423]"

julia> reshape(JSON3.read(as), (2,3))
2×3 reshape(::JSON3.Array{Float64, Base.CodeUnits{UInt8, String}, Vector{UInt64}}, 2, 3) with eltype Float64:
 0.534246  0.282277  0.140581
 0.841056  0.443697  0.427142
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to try. However, it seems JSON3.jl package is required and what I'm now using in my code is JSON.jl, so I'm not trying yet for being afraid that my code is going to be confusing. Does JSON3.jl work as substitution for JSON.jl ?

Comment: @ten JSON3 is a direct successor of JSON2, so technically has not much to do with JSON.jl. However, JSON3's author is well respected in Julia community for his work in CSV.jl and Arrow.jl, JSON3 is also very fast and well maintained